# {tableView reloadData} causes app to crash after section is deleted

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a defined a custom header view programmatically in the method:
`ViewForHeaderInSection`
Inside the custom view is a UIButton which has a target-action `method:"foodDeleteButtonPressed"`. I'm also setting the button's tag variable to the section number.

Here is the implementation of that method

```
-(void)foodDeleteButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
NSInteger index = [sender tag];
NSLog(@"Delete button pressed for section: %d", index);

FoodItem *tmpItem = [Cart.foodItemsArray objectAtIndex:index];

int ct = [tmpItem.sidesArray count];
if(ct > 0)
   {
    NSLog(@"About to delete %d sides", ct);
    [tmpItem.sidesArray removeAllObjects];
   }
else 
   {
    NSLog(@"The fooditem to be deleted has no side items");
   }

NSLog(@"About to remove object from ffod items array");

[Cart.foodItemsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[self.myOrderTable reloadData];


}
```

This method executes fine without the line:
`[self.myOrderTable reloadData];`

The moment I try to refresh my view after deleting the sections by trying to reload data.
My app crashes with the following stack trace:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:  '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:
>   (
>   CoreFoundation                      0x010325a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
>   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01186313 objc_exception_throw + 44
>   CoreFoundation                      0x010280a5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261
>   Restaurant                          0x00015c77 -
>   [MyOrderViewController tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:] + 827
>   UIKit                               0x0038de48 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _delegateWantsHeaderForSection:] + 152
>   UIKit                               0x004d8c01 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 116
>   UIKit                               0x004d6d88 -[UITableViewRowDatanumberOfRows] + 108
>   UIKit                               0x0038a677 -[UITableViewnoteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 132
>   UIKit                               0x00397708 -[UITableView reloadData] + 773
>   Restaurant                          0x00011eac -[MyOrderViewControllerfoodDeleteButtonPressed:] + 444
>   UIKit                               0x0031c4fd -[UIApplicationsendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
>   UIKit                               0x003ac799 -[UIControlsendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>   UIKit                               0x003aec2b -[UIControl(Internal)_sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]

The reload data is throwing an exception. How do I fix this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you removed the object, did you decrement the number of items that your table delegate reports to exist in the table?

This line:

Restaurant 0x00015c77 - [MyOrderViewController tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:] + 827

is doing an objectAtIndex on an array, likely the one you just removed the entry from.  I would guess it's asking for one more array element than exists.

Comment: where would I do that? should I post my viewforheaderinsection function code?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource

Answer (score 0):

!!!
[Cart.foodItemsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
!!!

Possibly this occurred when trying to delete a nonexistent index

Answer (score 0):

Check if

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

or

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

Return correct value (there could be NAN)